# Proofs that the classifying space of Connes' cycle category $\Lambda$ is $\mathbb C \mathbb P^\infty$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, cyclic-homology

Connes showed in [Cohomologie cyclique et foncteurs $Ext^n$ (1983)](https://alainconnes.org/wp-content/uploads/n83.pdf) that the classifying space of his [cycle category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cycle+category) $\Lambda$ is $\mathbb C \mathbb P^\infty = B(S^1) = K(\mathbb Z,2)$.

Connes' proof is not quite as conceptual as one might like. He shows that $|\Lambda|$ is simply-connected, and then computes its cohomology via an explicit resolution of the constant functor $\Lambda \to Ab$, $[n] \mapsto \mathbb Z$ via a double complex which is cooked-up by gluing together the usual way of resolving cyclic groups and the usual way of resolving simplicial objects, with a few modifications. He's able to get the ring structure on the cohomology using an endomorphism of this double complex. The result follows because $\mathbb C\mathbb P^\infty$ is characterized among simply-connected spaces by its cohomology ring.

Surely in the last nearly 40 years new proofs that $|\Lambda| \simeq \mathbb C \mathbb P^\infty$ have been found.

**Question 1:** What are some alternate proofs that $|\Lambda| \simeq \mathbb C \mathbb P^\infty$?

**Question 2:** (somewhat vague) In particular, is there a proof which somehow uses an explicit $S^1$ action on some category or simplicial set related to $\Lambda$?

Comment: Cisinski gives a nice proof of this in Proposition 8.5.19 of his _Les préfaisceaux comme modèles des types d'homotopie_.

Comment: Oh that's fantastic -- it looks a lot like the proof in Nikolaus and Scholze but of course Cisinski predates Nikolaus and Scholze considerably. Cisinski, like the nlab, denotes the paracyclic category by "$L$".

Comment: It's also in Hoyois' paper on the homotopy fixed points of the circle action on HH (corollary 1.2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This statement appears as Corollary B.4 in Nikolaus-Scholze's [On topological cyclic homology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01799); essentially, $\Lambda$ is the quotient of the *paracyclic* category $\Lambda_\infty$ by a free $B\mathbb Z$-action, which receives a final map from the simplicial category, hence is contractible.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I wasn't quite sure where to start in the vast literature on cyclic things. The first few references I tried just referred to Connes for the computation of the homotopy type.

Comment: Incidentally, I think there's a slight error in Nikolaus and Scholze's proof in Theorem B.3 that $\Delta \to \Lambda_\infty$ is a final functor. The criterion they formulate for contractibility does not apply because some of the finite intersections of $U_t$'s are empty rather than contractible. This is easily remedied by inductively showing that $\mathcal C[-n,n)$ is contractible by induction on $n$, using a similar glueing argument to their criterion, and passing to the colimit.

Answer (score 4):

Another proof appears as Lemma 8.1.1.15 and Remark 8.1.1.16 of [Igusa's *Higher Franz-Reidemeister torsion*](https://bookstore.ams.org/amsip-31). It uses spaces of graphs to verify that $|\Lambda|$ classifies oriented circle bundles.